# Epson Android SDK com.epson.epos2.printer.Printer.finalize() timed out

Tags: android, kotlin, crashlytics, thermal-printer, epson

After updating Epson Android SDK to v2.19.0, I got this crash from Crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.epson.epos2.printer.Printer.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
       at com.epson.epos2.printer.Printer.nativeEpos2Disconnect(Printer.java)
       at com.epson.epos2.printer.Printer.finalize(Printer.java:445)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:250)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This crash was very annoying to me. Because it happens to my > 20 users per day. My Crashlytics spammed with this crash. Does anyone know how to handle this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You should contact [EPSON near you](https://global.epson.com/other_products/point_of_sale_index.htm) and ask a question.

Comment: @kunif I think "contact us" from the Epson page is for discussing product problems, not SDK problem

Comment: If you contact them, they will introduce you to the department that provides technical support.

Comment: @kunif thanks for your help, this issue will be fixed by Epson in SDK V2.20.

Answer (score 2):

This issue will be fixed by Epson in SDK V2.20. Don't forget to check regularly on this site: https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=61